# Is there a way sending email using "mailto" with a code that checks if the user has a gmail or outlook (or other) account?

Tags: javascript, php, email, outlook, gmail

I want users on my website to contact me via email, and I want to make that easy and super user friendly for them.

Is there a way to identify with that email they are using? Because the default setting to this is Outlook. The other option is when a user changed his browsers settings/has an extension that navigates to Gmail (for example) instead of Outlook (http://blog.hubspot.com/marketing/set-gmail-as-browser-default-email-client-ht).

But for users who don't, is there an other way to do that?

*It's a Wordpress website (PHP) and I usually code with PHP and JS (jQuery).*

Comment: Or rather, it depends. It's not simple nor fool-proof, so may not be worthwhile.

Comment: And it would be creepy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run `mailto` links on many computers, for testing (for another project), and generally, the mailto link does open their default email program, without any plugins or anything. It may be different on Windows, but on Linux, Chrome OS, and Mac OS X, this is true. The possible reason that it is different on Windows is that all of the Microsoft products that come with windows are very tightly integrated into the system, and you can't *truly* change the default email program on Windows. But AFAIK the `mailto` link works the way you want it to on most operating systems.

Comment: 99% of my users are Windows users :(

Comment: Windows is no different: in my case, my mail client is Thunderbird, and that's what opens when I click on a mailto link

Comment: @ElectricWizard, I'm sorry, for you and for them. There isn't a way to detect what email program users use, besides having a text box for them to tell you. If websites were able to just detect these sort of things, it would be slightly scary, don't you think?

Comment: The system default email client is not the client that the user actually uses if they're a GMail customer.

Comment: @ChristopherDumas defiantly would be scarry! lol. Edward Snowden wont be hunted by the US gov anymore using this as proof to all web-evil in the world :P

Answer (score 1):

This is maybe not the answer you want, but have you considered setting up a contact form on your website? like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/contact).
This woud probably be the most easy way to let someone contact you without fiddling with external programms. You also woud have more controll about selectable topics and email-format.

Comment: sorry for not being very helpfull :( .But i thought it might be a good solution for what you are trying to achive. As far as my experience goes i just prefer this solution of leaving a way to contact.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can most definitely detect the provider they're using with simple regex. However, this will not work with people using, say, Google Apps. If you just want to recognise the domain used, you can always do something like:

```
$matches = array();

preg_match("/@(.*)/", "test@example.com", $matches);

return $matches[1];
```

However, this will only recognise the provider, not allow you to force another service. As already mentioned, I would suggest using a contact form instead of `mailto`.